# Writing Custom Authentication Filter Jasperserver 4.7

Tags: jasperserver

I am looking into jasperserver security. Our scenario is, our reports are hosted
in jasper server. We have our web application developed in JSF. Now from our jsf
application we want to invoke reports residing in jasper server.

Issue is our set of users are different from jasperserver. I was looking into jasper
server security and came to conclusion that it's using ACEGI security and we can also
write our custom authentication filters. Anybody has idea what would be the exact
process to write it? Any pointers will be helpful.

Best Regards,
Ben

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a similar problem, and I found this:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/adding-authentication-filters-and-using-profile-attributes